# When maas server goes down

Tags: maas

I'm running maas on 7 server.

When my maas server goes down, what happen?

When I and running 7 compute in maas cluster and just goes down one server,  what happen?

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing and testing with MAAS. The above answer is correct if the MAAS goes down you do not actually loose any services. When the service comes back up then it's up and there is no disruption of services. The thing is, i haven't found a good way to run MAAS in an HA setup or proper documentation on which parts of the MAAS need to be backed up so that you can recover the server. Frankly MAAS documentation is lacking quite a bit.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the video below

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HjKHD5rv7A

you can unplug the MAAS and Landscape server and the stack will stay online

Comment: -1 because low quality answer. While this answer corresponds to the question asked, linking to a lengthy 45-min video on YouTube is hardly useful at all. Unless you note at which minutes and seconds the speech of video is quoted, this is a low-quality answer.